# How can I keep a Sencha Touch 2 dataview scrollable but turn off scrolling behaviour?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I would like to keep the dataview scrollable so that I can use the scrollBy and scrollTo functions, but I don't want the user to be able to swipe to scroll the dataview. But I still need to respond to the swipe gesture.

I was thinking that maybe adjusting the momentumEasing values could do it. But I'm having trouble getting my changes to be used by the scroller. In my dataview config I have the following code, but it changes nothing about the scroller behaviour:

```
scrollable: {
      momentumEasing: {
        momentum: {
          acceleration: 0,
          friction: 999999
        },
        bounce: {
          acceleration: 0,
          springTension: 0
        }
      }
    }
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work? Alternatively, are there any other, cleaner ways to acheive what I'm after? I also will need to remove the scollbar from appearing, but I assume that can be done with CSS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to override the `onDragStart` method in your scroller so it does nothing.

```
container.getScrollable().getScroller().onDragStart = null;
```